# print default value wtforms in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, wtforms

I'm using WTforms in Flask with Jinja2. I create a form like this:

```
def print_form(request, db):
    class F(Form):
        name = StringField('name', default='Mike')
        video = SelectField(
            'Programming Language',
            choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain     Text')],default='py'
        )

    form1 = F(request.form)

    data = {'form1' : form1}
    rtemplate = jinja_env2.get_template('test.html')
    data = rtemplate.render(**data)
```

Then I print the form in Jinja2 like this:

```
                <table>
                {% for field in form1 %}
                    <tr>
                    {% if field.type == "BooleanField" %}
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{ field }} {{ field.label }}</td>
                    {% elif field.type == "HiddenField" %}
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>                       
                    {% elif field.type == "SelectField" %}
                         <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>                       

                    {% else %}
                        <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
                        <td>{{ field }}</td>
                    {% endif %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
```

However I cannot find how to prefill the default value of the TextField, it's works automatically with the SelectField.

Comment: It works for me, just checked. `default='something'` makes everything. And btw, `TextField` would be deprecated in WTForms 3, so use `StringField`

Comment: I also tried it with StringField but doesn't fill the field in the html

Comment: What is the version of `WTForms` package?

Comment: WTForms version 2.1

Comment: Are you sure you are not populating form with already created object with `name == ''`?

Comment: I updated my code so it's complete now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124111/discussion-between-vishes-shell-and-user3605780).